# Summarising data to list different combinations of row information

Tags: sql

I need to list all possible combinations of department code and credit limit from a table called 'employees'. I should also count the number of employees who are in each of these categories, sort the rows by department code and then credit limit in a descending order.

I have had many attempts, here is my latest;

```
SELECT dept_code COUNT(credit_limit)  as
num_of employees
FROM L_EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY num_of_employees
ORDER BY dept_code, credit_limit, COUNT(credit_limit) DESC;
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `group by` `dept_code` and `credit_limit`, which will give you all unique combinations of these two fields, and then `count()` will give you the count of employees within each group (combination):

```
SELECT dept_code, credit_limit, COUNT(*) as num_of_employees
FROM L_EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY dept_code, credit_limit
ORDER BY dept_code, credit_limit DESC;
```